# use TIdHTTP in Delphi to simulate curl command with user authentication

Tags: delphi, curl, indy10

I am trying to use `TIdHTTP` in Delphi to simulate the following curl operation:

```
curl -X POST -F "message={\"user_email\" : \"useremail@domain.com\" , \"user_password\" : \"UserPassword\"}" "https://esm-db.eu/esmws/generate-signed-message/1/query" > token.txt
```

The guidelines from the server side are given in: https://esm-db.eu/esmws/generate-signed-message/1/query-options.html

The detailed output from a successful curl connection is the following:

```
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
*   Trying 193.206.88.90...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to esm-db.eu (193.206.88.90) port 443 (#0)
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with esm-db.eu port 443 (step 1/3)
* schannel: checking server certificate revocation
* schannel: sending initial handshake data: sending 174 bytes...
* schannel: sent initial handshake data: sent 174 bytes
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with esm-db.eu port 443 (step 2/3)
* schannel: failed to receive handshake, need more data
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with esm-db.eu port 443 (step 2/3)
* schannel: encrypted data got 2954
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 2954 length 4096
* schannel: sending next handshake data: sending 93 bytes...
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with esm-db.eu port 443 (step 2/3)
* schannel: encrypted data got 258
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 258 length 4096
* schannel: SSL/TLS handshake complete
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with esm-db.eu port 443 (step 3/3)
* schannel: stored credential handle in session cache
> POST /esmws/generate-signed-message/1/query HTTP/1.1
> Host: esm-db.eu
> User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 217
> Expect: 100-continue
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------7682f54661679429
>
* schannel: client wants to read 102400 bytes
* schannel: encdata_buffer resized 103424
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 0 length 103424
* schannel: encrypted data got 54
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 54 length 103424
* schannel: decrypted data length: 25
* schannel: decrypted data added: 25
* schannel: decrypted data cached: offset 25 length 102400
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 0 length 103424
* schannel: decrypted data buffer: offset 25 length 102400
* schannel: schannel_recv cleanup
* schannel: decrypted data returned 25
* schannel: decrypted data buffer: offset 0 length 102400
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
* schannel: client wants to read 102400 bytes
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 0 length 103424
* schannel: encrypted data got 924
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 924 length 103424
* schannel: decrypted data length: 895
* schannel: decrypted data added: 895
* schannel: decrypted data cached: offset 895 length 102400
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 0 length 103424
* schannel: decrypted data buffer: offset 895 length 102400
* schannel: schannel_recv cleanup
* schannel: decrypted data returned 895
* schannel: decrypted data buffer: offset 0 length 102400
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.10.3
< Date: Sun, 08 Nov 2020 23:20:51 GMT
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
< Content-Length: 649
< Connection: keep-alive
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS
<
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNED MESSAGE-----
Hash: SHA256
```

However, with `TIdHTTP` I keep getting an `HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request` error. What am I doing wrong?

```pascal
procedure TMainForm.HTTPGetTokenFile;
var
  IdHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  Params: TIdMultipartFormDataStream;
  LHandler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
begin
  try
    Params := TIdMultipartFormDataStream.Create;
    Params.AddFormField('message', '{\"user_email\" : \"useremail@domain.com\" , \"user_password\" : \"UserPassword\"}');
    try
      IdHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
      try
        LHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(IdHTTP);
        LHandler.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1;
        IdHTTP.IOHandler := LHandler;
        IdHTTP.Request.Accept := 'application/json, text/plain;q=0.9, text/html;q=0.8';
        IdHTTP.Request.ContentType := 'application/json';
        Memo1.Text := IdHTTP.Post('https://esm-db.eu/esmws/generate-signed-message/1/query', Params);
      finally
        IdHTTP.Free;
      end;
    finally
      Params.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      ShowMessage('Error: ' + E.ToString);
  end;
end;
```

**UPDATE**: I removed the `\` characters in the JSON, but I am still getting the `HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request` error.

```pascal
procedure TMainForm.HTTPGetTokenFile;
var
  IdHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  Params: TIdMultipartFormDataStream;
  LHandler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
begin
  try
    Params := TIdMultipartFormDataStream.Create;
    Params.AddFormField('message', '{"user_email" : "useremail@domain.com" , "user_password" : "UserPassword"}');
    try
      IdHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
      try
        LHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(IdHTTP);
        LHandler.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1;
        IdHTTP.IOHandler := LHandler;
        IdHTTP.Request.Accept := 'application/json, text/plain;q=0.9, text/html;q=0.8';
        IdHTTP.Request.ContentType := 'application/json';
        Memo1.Text := IdHTTP.Post('https://esm-db.eu/esmws/generate-signed-message/1/query', Params);
      finally
        IdHTTP.Free;
      end;
    finally
      Params.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      ShowMessage('Error: ' + E.ToString);
  end;
end;
```

The dump from `TIdHTTP` is the following:

```
Stat Connected.
Sent 9/11/2020 4:36:55 ??: POST /esmws/generate-signed-message/1/query HTTP/1.0<EOL>Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------110920163653921<EOL>Content-Length: 257<EOL>Host: esm-db.eu<EOL>Accept: application/json, text/plain;q=0.9, text/html;q=0.8<EOL>Accept-Encoding: identity<EOL>User-Agent: Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)<EOL><EOL>
Sent 9/11/2020 4:36:55 ??: ----------110920163653921<EOL>Content-Disposition: form-data; name="message"<EOL>Content-Type: text/plain<EOL>Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable<EOL><EOL>{"user_email" : "s.antoniou@seismosoft.com" , "user_password" : "passw=<EOL>ord"}<EOL>----------110920163653921--<EOL>
Recv 9/11/2020 4:36:55 ??: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request<EOL>Server: nginx/1.10.3<EOL>Date: Mon, 09 Nov 2020 14:36:56 GMT<EOL>Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8<EOL>Content-Length: 121<EOL>Connection: close<EOL>Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *<EOL>Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS<EOL><EOL>{"http_code": 400, "http_label": "Bad Request", "exit_message": "ERROR: improper specification / unrecognized parameter"}
Stat Disconnected.
Stat Disconnected.
Stat Disconnected.
```

It seems that the arguement of the `AddFormField()` function has a limit of 70 characters and the final 3 characters seem to be cut off. Can I increase this limit or should I decrease the size of the value passed (e.g. by removing the unnecessary spaces)?

Comment: I doubt that you need to use the \ character to escape the double quote in the Delphi version

Comment: You provided a partial dump (headers only, no body data) of the curl request, but you didn’t provide any dump of the TIdHTTP request for comparison.  Please provide full dumps of both requests, otherwise there is no way for us to see exactly how the TIdHTTP request differs from the curl request to know what the server might be considering is bad.

Comment: For curl you mean to output things through -verbose Debug or something different?
Regarding TIdHTTP I am struggling for hours to figure out how to do it. With IdLogDebug I cannot find a way to save the data for a file or to export them to a TMemo, with TIdInterceptSimLog I can specify a file but I keep on getting a 105 I/O error and the created file have no contents.

Comment: @SteliosAntoniou for curl, try the [`--trace` option](https://ec.haxx.se/usingcurl/usingcurl-verbose/usingcurl-trace). For TIdHTTP, try `TIdLogFile`.

Comment: @Remy Many thanks for the prompt reply. I will give them a try and come back to you. Cheers

Comment: @Remy it seems that the problem was with the size of the parameter passed with AddFormField. There seems to be a limit of 70 characters and the final 3 characters of the string were cut-off in two (at the password). Logging with Intercept helped me identifiy the problem, when I removed the unnecessary spaces in the text string and the argument became 67-68 chafracters long the procedure worked fine providing the correct token.txt file. Many thanks for the assistance and the patience!

Comment: @RemyLebeau indeed, I tried to search for this limit in the Delphi libraries and I could not find anything. 
However, what troubles me is why the curl commands from the command prompt pass without problems?

Comment: @SteliosAntoniou I have updated my answer.

Comment: @RemyLebeau many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Dave mentioned in a comment, you need to remove the `\` characters in your JSON data. Delphi does not escape characters the same way a command line processor does. `"` is not a reserved character in Delphi, so there is no need to escape a `"` character in a Delphi string literal.

Also, on a side note, the assignment of `IdHTTP.Request.ContentType` is redundant in this situation and should be removed. `Post()`'ing a `TIdMultiPartFormDataStream` will overwrite the `ContentType` with its own value, ignoring whatever you assign.

Try this instead:

```pascal
procedure TMainForm.HTTPGetTokenFile;
var
  IdHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  Params: TIdMultipartFormDataStream;
  LHandler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
begin
  try
    Params := TIdMultipartFormDataStream.Create;
    try
      Params.AddFormField('message', '{"user_email" : "useremail@domain.com" , "user_password" : "UserPassword"}');

      IdHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
      try
        LHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(IdHTTP);
        LHandler.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1;
        IdHTTP.IOHandler := LHandler;
        IdHTTP.Request.Accept := 'application/json, text/plain;q=0.9, text/html;q=0.8';
        Memo1.Text := IdHTTP.Post('https://esm-db.eu/esmws/generate-signed-message/1/query', Params);
      finally
        IdHTTP.Free;
      end;
    finally
      Params.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      ShowMessage('Error: ' + E.ToString);
  end;
end;
```

---

**UPDATE:** turns out that `TIdMultiPartFormDataStream` is sending your JSON in `Quoted-Printable` format, where a "soft" line break is being inserted into the middle of your JSON every 70 characters. Apparently, your server does not support that encoding properly.  By default, curl does not use `Quoted-Printable` for a webform submission unless you explicitly tell it to do so.

You can disable the `Quoted-Printable` encoding in `TIdMultipartFormDataStream` by either:

1. setting the `TIdFormDataField.ContentTransfer` property to either `'7bit'`, `'8bit'`, `'binary'`, or `''` (which is effectively the same as `'7bit'` but without notifying the server explicitly via a `Content-Transfer-Encoding` header), eg:

```pascal
procedure TMainForm.HTTPGetTokenFile;
var
  IdHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  Params: TIdMultipartFormDataStream;
  LHandler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
begin
  try
    Params := TIdMultipartFormDataStream.Create;
    try
      with Params.AddFormField('message', '{"user_email" : "useremail@domain.com" , "user_password" : "UserPassword"}') do
      begin
        Charset := 'utf-8';
        ContentTransfer := '8bit';
      end;

      IdHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
      try
        LHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(IdHTTP);
        LHandler.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1;
        IdHTTP.IOHandler := LHandler;
        IdHTTP.Request.Accept := 'application/json, text/plain;q=0.9, text/html;q=0.8';
        Memo1.Text := IdHTTP.Post('https://esm-db.eu/esmws/generate-signed-message/1/query', Params);
      finally
        IdHTTP.Free;
      end;
    finally
      Params.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      ShowMessage('Error: ' + E.ToString);
  end;
end;
```

2. using the `AddFormField()` overload that takes a `TStream` instead of a `String`.  You can put your JSON into a `TStringStream`, eg:

```pascal
procedure TMainForm.HTTPGetTokenFile;
var
  IdHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  Params: TIdMultipartFormDataStream;
  LHandler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
  LJSON: TStringStream;
begin
  try
    LJSON := TStringStream.Create('{"user_email" : "useremail@domain.com" , "user_password" : "UserPassword"}', TEncoding.UTF8);
    try
      Params := TIdMultipartFormDataStream.Create;
      try
        with Params.AddFormField('message', 'text/plain', 'utf-8', LJSON) do
          ContentTransfer := '8bit';
    
        IdHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
        try
          LHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(IdHTTP);
          LHandler.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1;
          IdHTTP.IOHandler := LHandler;
          IdHTTP.Request.Accept := 'application/json, text/plain;q=0.9, text/html;q=0.8';
          Memo1.Text := IdHTTP.Post('https://esm-db.eu/esmws/generate-signed-message/1/query', Params);
        finally
          IdHTTP.Free;
        end;
      finally
        Params.Free;
      end;
    finally
      LJSON.Free;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      ShowMessage('Error: ' + E.ToString);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you for your asnwers. 
Unfortunately, even without the \ character I still get the 'HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request' error.

Comment: @SteliosAntoniou then there is something else wrong with your setup of TIdHTTP that we can't see. You are just going to have to capture the actual request data generated by curl and TIdHTTP and compare them for differences, and then adjust your Delphi code accordingly.

Comment: not sure I understand, sorry. How can I capture the data generated? Regarding my setup of TIdHTTP,  you mean in my Indy installation, right?

Comment: @SteliosAntoniou no, I mean the property setup. Clearly something is different between curl and TIdHTTP. To capture the raw requests, since you are using HTTPS, you can enable curl's [verbose](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-v) or [trace](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#--trace) output, and attach one of Indy's `TIdLog...` components to the `TIdHTTP.Intercept` property.

Comment: '@RemyLeeau' thanks. I will give it a try (I need to spend some time studying) and come back to you guys if I still cannot make it work. Thanks